# What is SubField in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I stumble on an expression I do not understand. What is **SubField**? I found an example, but I do not know how to prepare data so it will work. Example is below. I would like to know how to prepare Sheet1 in Excel so this will work.

This example filters a list starting in cell A1 on Sheet1 to display only the entries in which the values of field one contain a SubField, Admin Division 1 (State/province/other), where the value is Washington.

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:="Washington", _
 SubField:="Admin Division 1 (State/province/other)"
```

Example is taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is used for a specific data type, like geography or stocks data type.

You can see in this [Forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-difference-in-sort-with-add2-and-add-sortfields-add2-vs-sortfields-add.1072594/) the third comment clarifies this is a resource usable on new versions and with Office 365 accounts.

This two microsoft support website [Data types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-data-types-stocks-and-geography-61a33056-9935-484f-8ac8-f1a89e210877) and [Stockhistory function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stockhistory-function-1ac8b5b3-5f62-4d94-8ab8-7504ec7239a8) helps clarifying the subject. On the "Data types" you will be able to see a table example for a usable `Subfield`code, as the example below (found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)):

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:="10", _
 Operator:=xlTop10Items, _
 SubField:="Population"
```

With this code you would be able to sort the second table (the geography one) showing the top 10 countries by population.

I know it is still something a bit vague, but it clarified the question for me.